# SEO for dynamic webpages

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I have created an advertising website in php mysql. I have nearly 200 files for each location. This 200 files will be for example : for selling cars, bikes etc. In all the title, head, keywords I used a variable x which is the location. Then I used a scripting language to open each of the 200 files, replace x with location name, save it in different names. For ex: location1_websitename_cars.php. There are more than million locations. I created 200× million files like these. But I cannot host my website economically due to file number limitation on shared hosting servers.

My intention for replicating 200 files for each location was that google search engine can find my pages when user searches the location name as keyword. As per my understanding google crawls through the existing pages in server and find the location name as keyword and this results in inclusion of webpage in search results. Since this approach wont work with shared hosting, I changed strategy.

I am able to generate files required for a location dynamically according to the user selected location from the home page of my website. In this case I just need to store 200 files in my server. All pages would be accessible from home page of website. But I don’t know whether that pages would accessible from google search. For ex: if user types : "location1 www.mywebsite.com cars ", that php page wont be displayed as this page don’t exist in server. It is to be dynamically created.

To simply put: " Is there a way of including my website pages in google search results if that page don’t exist in server. It would be dynamically created once user selects some input and submit it from the home page.

Comment: I don't think google cares if the page "exists" on the server or not - the crawler is still very capable of finding dynamic pages. For instance, I just googled "seo for dynamic webpages" and this question was among the results. Surely StackOverflow does not create a hard coded file for every question asked... and Google was still able to find this dynamically generated page.

Comment: Mark Thanks for your time. So if I use URL variable for creating each pages, it would be accessible from search engine results ? Is this the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

Google use URL as identifier for pages not the files on the server.

To detect URLs, Google use robots following links on the web (`<a>`, `<link>`, etc.).

If you want your page to get found and indexed by Google, do not worry about your files on server but on your URLs and internal linking. You need to create a navigation to all the possible pages to let robots access it.

NB: URLs with parameters work but it is preferable to rewrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines won't have any problem following your dynamically created pages, but you will need to first create links to those pages from another page that the search engines do know about (eg: your home page).  Once you link to your dynamic pages, they can be indexed.

The more pages and sites (especially high values sites) that link to your pages, the higher up in the search results your pages will be (of course there are other factors that affect this as well).  Also if you want to test any of this without wading through pages upon pages of search results, google: "***site***:www.yourwebsite.com yoursearchterms"